# what does the square bracket of style in className does

Tags: reactjs

For the code below

```
import styles from './index.module.scss';
...
return (
        <div
            className={classNames(styles.wrapper, {
                [styles.scrolling]: isScrolling
            })}
            ref={calendarRef}
        >
```

what does

```
[styles.scrolling]: isScrolling
```

achieve?

Answer (score 1):

[`classNames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) helps you to generate class names conditionally

`className={classNames(styles.wrapper)}` is `className="wrapper"`

`className={classNames(styles.wrapper, styles.scrolling)}` is `className="wrapper scrolling"`

But in some cases, you don't want to have `scrolling` in your class names, so we have that conditional class name with a true/false value (`isScrolling`)

---

```
className={classNames(styles.wrapper, {
   [styles.scrolling]: true
})}
```

will generate

```
className="wrapper scrolling"
```

---

```
className={classNames(styles.wrapper, {
   [styles.scrolling]: false
})}
```

will generate

```
className="wrapper"
```

---

A side note that `styles.wrapper` and `styles.scrolling` are like variables, so they will be possibly hashed or uglified on production